# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. (Python / SKFlow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

this is my first question after using this site for many years - please correct me if I'm doing something wrong...

I'm trying to train a Deep Neural Network Classifier using the SKFlow part of TensorFlow which should make this pretty simple. I'm constantly getting this `ValueError` when passing my data to the Classifiers `fit` method.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./train_ann.py", line 55, in <module>
clf.fit(x_train.values, y_train.values, steps=1000)
  File "/home/maurice/Dev/pyvenv/itslb/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 235, in fit
epochs=None)
  File "/home/maurice/Dev/pyvenv/itslb/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 82, in _get_input_fn
epochs=epochs)
  File "/home/maurice/Dev/pyvenv/itslb/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/data_feeder.py", line 116, in setup_train_data_feeder
x, y, n_classes, batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, epochs=epochs)
  File "/home/maurice/Dev/pyvenv/itslb/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/data_feeder.py", line 241, in __init__
self.x = check_array(x, dtype=x_dtype)
  File "/home/maurice/Dev/pyvenv/itslb/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/data_feeder.py", line 188, in check_array
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=None, copy=False)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The relevant code looks like this:

```
# The y_train dataframe now contains only the type_id column which contains only integers
y_train = y_train[["type_id"]]

# Convert the numpy arrays to lists
x_train["vector"] = x_train.vector.map(lambda x: x.tolist())

# Get the number of classes for the classifier
n_classes = len(list(y_train.type_id.unique()))

# Create a deep neural network classifier
clf = skflow.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[2000, 2000, 1500, 1000],
    n_classes=n_classes,
    model_dir='/home/maurice/Dev/test/TFModel01'
)

# Start training the classifier
clf.fit(x_train, y_train, steps=1000)
```

The `x_train` Data Frame looks like this (it contains only one column):

```
                                                vector
324  [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, ...
471  [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, ...
...
```

`y_train` looks like this:

```
     type_id
887       10
507        2
...
```

I tried to use the solutions so similar questions, but either I'm doing it wrong or there is a different problem.

**What I already tried:**

- Not converting the Numpy Array to a list, same error
- Making sure that each element in x_train.vector has the same length - it has
- Making sure that each element in x_train.vector is of the same type - done
- Converting x_train.vector to Integers - same result

**Edit**

I did some more research and was able to find out how the function that raises the exception is called.

```
for index, row in x_train.iterrows():
    print(type(row))
    print(row)
    array = np.array(row, dtype=np.float32, order=None, copy=False)
```

This reproduces the error. The output shows me that `row` is of type `pandas.core.series.Series` - this explains the Exception.

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
vector    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, ...
Name: 599, dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./train_ann.py", line 34, in <module>
    array = np.array(row, dtype=np.float32, order=No
```

Can you guys point me to a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does `fit` expect?  dataframes?  arrays?

Comment: Unfortunately the [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#DNNClassifier) isn't very specific about that. `tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier.fit(x=None, y=None, input_fn=None, steps=None, batch_size=None, monitors=None, max_steps=None)

See Trainable.` Unfortunately I can't find this "Trainable" section in the docs. The source code handles DataFrames, Lists and h5py (?) Datasets.

Comment: The error indicates that it is trying to convert an input (`x`?) into an array: `np.array(x,...)`.  What does `np.array(x_train)`? produce?  Same for `y_train`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `model.fit` does not accept a list of sequences, hence you need to create either a list of list or a multi-dimensional np.ndarray. This should help you:

```
x_train =[arr for arr in x_train.vector]
x_train = np.asarray(x_train)

y_train = np.asarray(y_train[["type_id"]].values)

...
model.fit(x_train,
```